# I am trying to find the conditions where $(x - y)^z = x + y$ where all elements are non-zero natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have been thinking about this problem for bit and cannot seem to figure it out. If the $GCD(x, y) = GCD(x + y, x - y) = 2$, solutions will exist; however, I am more interested in the case where solutions do not exist. I know that if both $x$ and $y$ are odd, solutions will also exist. Since $(x + y) | (x - y)^z$, my guess is that when $GCD(x, y) = GCD(x + y, x - y) = 1$, and one is odd and the other is even, there will be no possibility of solutions existing. I am just not sure how to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $a,b\ge 1$ satisfy $gcd(a, b)=1$ and $a\mid b^k$. Then $a\mid b$ and hence $a=b=1$.

For $a=x+y$ and $b=x-y$ then $(x+y)\mid (x-y)^z$ implies that $x+y=x-y=1$ and
hence $y=0$, a contradiction. So the equation $(x-y)^z=x+y$ has no solution for positive integers with $gcd(x+y,x-y)=1$.

Comment: Thank you! That helps quite a bit.